# Facebook.Client C# Post dialog

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook.Client 1.0.2 library to post a link with a personal comment to it, using the Session.ShowFeedDialog method. I've almost understand all the parameters, but the first one, the toId, is puzzling me: the call give me a generic error with empty or null string, and if I set it with my facebook app id, it says that the parameter is not valid.
What I've to pass in this parameter to make it work?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should put there user id, instead of app id. If it's your id (logged user id), it will be post on your wall, if it's your friend id, it will be post as your message on his wall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will keep in mind, if I met again this problem. Actually the project is over, and I've no way to test your suggestion, 'cause I'm not developing in C# at this time...